# Erro em query com WHERE E COUNT no Oracle. "SQL command not properly ended"

Tags: sql, oracle

Tenho a seguinte query:

```
INSERT INTO TB_CLASSIFICACAO_UG 
    (COD_CLASSIFICACAO_UG, TXT_DESCRICAO, IND_ATIVO) 
VALUES 
    (SEQ_COD_TB_CLASSIFICACAO_UG.nextval, 'TESTANDO', 1)
WHERE 
    (SELECT COUNT(TXT_DESCRICAO) FROM TB_CLASSIFICACAO_UG WHERE TXT_DESCRICAO = 'TESTANDO') = 0
```

Essa query gera o erro:

```
"SQL command not properly ended"
```

Porém se eu rodar somente a primeira parte ela funciona.

```
INSERT INTO TB_CLASSIFICACAO_UG 
    (COD_CLASSIFICACAO_UG, TXT_DESCRICAO, IND_ATIVO) 
VALUES 
    (SEQ_COD_TB_CLASSIFICACAO_UG.nextval, 'TESTANDO', 1)
```

E se eu rodar a segunda parte também.

```
(SELECT COUNT(TXT_DESCRICAO) FROM TB_CLASSIFICACAO_UG WHERE TXT_DESCRICAO = 'TESTANDO') = 0
```

O que será que estou fazendo de errado?

O que eu quero no final das contas é tipo um INSERT IF NOT EXISTS. Alguma sugestão de query? Já tentei de outras formas além dessa e não funcionou.

Answer (score 1):

O comando `INSERT` (SQL ANSI) não aceita a clausula `WHERE`, essa necessidade de inserir apenas caso não exista é relativamente comum mas sua implementação muda conforme o banco, uma abordagem que recomendo é verificar isso no código da sua aplicação de forma que a lógica fique mais clara.

Caso você opte por fazer tudo no SQL ainda é possível, da seguinte maneira(no oracle):

```
begin
  insert into TB_CLASSIFICACAO_UG
         (COD_CLASSIFICACAO_UG, TXT_DESCRICAO, IND_ATIVO) 
  values (SEQ_COD_TB_CLASSIFICACAO_UG.nextval, 'TESTANDO', 1)
  ;
  commit;
exception
  when DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX
  then ROLLBACK;
end;
```

Comment: O que é esse DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX

Comment: É um tipo de exceção que o Oracle lança quando há duplicidade do índice (Duplication of value on index)

Comment: Mas como ele sabe que o índice é o TXT_DESCRICAO?

Comment: Imaginei que já que você pretende evitar a duplicação de um determinado campo você poderia ter adicionado um índice a ele, isso não é necessariamente verdade mas pode ser interessante especialmente se você pretende fazer essa verificação com frequência

Answer (score 0):

Tente inverter a ordem de sua query para algo semelhante ao seguinte:

```
INSERT INTO TB_CLASSIFICACAO_UG 
    (SELECT COD_CLASSIFICACAO_UG, TXT_DESCRICAO, IND_ATIVO FROM TB_CLASSIFICACAO_UG WHERE TXT_DESCRICAO <> 'TESTANDO')
VALUES 
(SEQ_COD_TB_CLASSIFICACAO_UG.nextval, 'TESTANDO', 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Para a inserção condicional no Oracle você pode utilizar a cláusula [`MERGE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606)

```sql
MERGE
   INTO  TB_CLASSIFICACAO_UG
   USING (SELECT COUNT(TXT_DESCRICAO) AS count FROM TB_CLASSIFICACAO_UG WHERE TXT_DESCRICAO = 'TESTANDO') s
     ON   (s.count > 0)
 WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
     INSERT (COD_CLASSIFICACAO_UG, TXT_DESCRICAO, IND_ATIVO)
     VALUES (SEQ_COD_TB_CLASSIFICACAO_UG.nextval, 'TESTANDO', 1);
```

Teste no SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3944a4/2

Answer (score 0):

Para que um registro seja inserido somente se ainda não existir, os bancos de dados possuem restrições de chave única.

No seu exemplo, basta transformar o campo TXT_DESCRICAO em uma chave única utilizando o comando:

```
ALTER TABLE TB_CLASSIFICACAO_UG
ADD CONSTRAINT TB_CLASSIF_TXT UNIQUE (TXT_DESCRICAO);
```

Desta forma, qualquer rotina ou query será impedida de inserir um valor para TXT_DESCRICAO que já exista na tabela.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui chegar a uma solução para o meu problema:

```
INSERT INTO TB_CLASSIFICACAO_UG 
    (COD_CLASSIFICACAO_UG, TXT_DESCRICAO, IND_ATIVO) 
VALUES 
    (SEQ_COD_TB_CLASSIFICACAO_UG.nextval, (SELECT '" + descricao + "' FROM dual WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM TB_CLASSIFICACAO_UG WHERE TXT_DESCRICAO = '" + descricao + "')) , 1);
```